# The "Show Applications" menu, and Ubuntu Dock

Tags: ubuntu-dock

So if I am trying to make Ubuntu look like mac, sometimes I want to get rid of the dock. After disabling the "Ubuntu Dock" extension, I get no dock, but when I hit the Super Key/ Windows Key, I see the Dock in the menu. Also, there is a triangle in the "Ubuntu Dock", making it impossible to re-enable it.

Running Kinetic Kudu 22.10